CUDA Kernel Parameters cause "cudaMemcpy an illegal memory access was encountered"

I want to change the variables M, N  by the argv parameters when the code is executed.

My code tvm_test.cu is below:


#include <cuda_fp16.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <assert.h>

#define CUDA_CHECK(status)                                                    \
    {                                                                         \
        cudaError_t error = status;                                           \
        if (error != cudaSuccess)                                             \
        {                                                                     \
            std::cerr << "Got bad cuda status: " << cudaGetErrorString(error) \
                      << " at line: " << __LINE__ << std::endl;               \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                               \
        }                                                                     \
    }

__device__ int M=8192,N=8192;
const int tx = 1024, ty = 1, tz = 1;
const int element_per_thread = 256;
// const int M = 2048, N = 2048;


__global__
void int2half_I2H(int8_t* __restrict__ input, half* __restrict__ output){
    #pragma unroll
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++ i){
        output[(blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x) * 256 + i] = __int2half_rn(input[(blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x) * 256 + i]);
    }
}

__global__
void int2half_I2H_tvm(int8_t* input, half* output, int M, int N){
    #pragma unroll
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++ i){
        output[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (M * N) / 256] = \
            __int2half_rn(input[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (M * N) / 256]);
    }
}

__global__
void int2half_I2H_tvm(int8_t* input, half* output){
    int rM = 8192;
    int rN = 8192;
    // #pragma unroll
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++ i){
        output[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (rM * rN) / 256] = \
            __int2half_rn(input[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (rM * rN) / 256]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    M=atoi(argv[1]); 
    N=atoi(argv[2]); 
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    // for int2half
    int8_t *input = (int8_t *)malloc(M * N); 
    half *output_int2half = (half *)malloc(M * N * 2);

    // for prmt, + 128
    int8_t *input_preprocess = (int8_t *)malloc(M * N); 
    half *output_prmt = (half *)malloc(M * N * 2);

    // result
    float *golden = (float *)malloc(M * N * 4);

    // rand input [-10, 10]
    for(int i = 0; i < M * N; ++ i){
        input[i] = (int8_t)((rand() % 21) - 10);
        golden[i] = (float)input[i];
    }
    
    // preprocess + 128
    for(int i = 0; i < M * N; ++ i){
        input_preprocess[i] = input[i] + 128;
    }
    
    int8_t *d_input;
    int8_t *d_input_preprocess;
    half *d_output_int2half;
    half *d_output_prmt;

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_input, M * N));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_input_preprocess, M * N));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_output_int2half, M * N * 2));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_output_prmt, M * N * 2));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_input, input, M * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_input_preprocess, input_preprocess, M * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

   
    
    dim3 dimBlock(1024);
    dim3 dimGrid(256);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++ i){
        // printf("%d %d", M, N);
        //int2half_I2H_tvm<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>> (d_input, d_output_int2half);
        int2half_I2H_tvm<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>> (d_input, d_output_int2half,M,N);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(output_prmt, d_output_prmt, M * N * 2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(output_int2half, d_output_int2half, M * N * 2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

   
}


But after the compile instruction nvcc -o tvm_test tvm_test.cu,we run ./tvm_test 8192 8192.

The error: Got bad cuda status: an illegal memory access was encountered at line: 104. The line of code is CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(output_prmt, d_output_prmt, M * N * 2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));.


We use the int2half_I2H function instead of the int2half_I2H_tvm function. There is no error!

Remove __device__ from the global variables. (In fact, make M and N local to main. It's never to soon to stop using globals.)

Please CUDA_CHECK the cudaDeviceSynchronize() call and ideally also do a CUDA_CHECK(cudaGetLastError()); before synchronization to check if the launch succeeded at all.

Does this answer your question? How can I debug code 700 "illegal memory access" aka `CUDA_EXCEPTION_14, Warp Illegal Address`?


This is not legal in CUDA:
__device__ int M=8192,N=8192;
...
M=atoi(argv[1]); 
N=atoi(argv[2]); 

In CUDA, device variables (or device memory) is not directly accessible by host code.  There are various ways to address this via refactoring; for example you could get rid of the __device__ variable usage altogether, and pass those parameters via kernel arguments.  Perhaps the simplest change might be to convert those from __device__ to __managed__.

This calculation can lead to integer overflow:
i * (M * N)

Your M and N are 8192.  i can take on values up to 255.  If you multiply those 3 together, you can end up with a number (17,112,760,320) that is larger than the largest positive value that could be stored in a int (around 2,000,000,000) or unsigned (around 4,000,000,000) quantity.  This is the proximal issue that is causing the illegal access.  We could address this by promoting one of the quantities to long long to force the calculation to be done at 64 bits.  There are other possible fixes, of course.  (The other kernel variant that you indicate is working, is not subject to this particular overflow issue.)

If it were me, I would not use a global variable M that has the same name as a kernel parameter M (and likewise for N). I find it confusing. Yes, it is not illegal, but it immediately makes me scratch my head to try and remember which one will be applicable.


When I address those 3 issues, your code seems to run without error for me:
# cat t216.cu
#include <cuda_fp16.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <assert.h>

#define CUDA_CHECK(status)                                                    \
    {                                                                         \
        cudaError_t error = status;                                           \
        if (error != cudaSuccess)                                             \
        {                                                                     \
            std::cerr << "Got bad cuda status: " << cudaGetErrorString(error) \
                      << " at line: " << __LINE__ << std::endl;               \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                               \
        }                                                                     \
    }

__managed__ int M=8192,N=8192;


__global__
void int2half_I2H(int8_t* __restrict__ input, half* __restrict__ output){
    #pragma unroll
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++ i){
        output[(blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x) * 256 + i] = __int2half_rn(input[(blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x) * 256 + i]);
    }
}

__global__
void int2half_I2H_tvm(int8_t* input, half* output, long long kM, long long kN){
    #pragma unroll
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++ i){
        output[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (kM * kN) / 256] = \
            __int2half_rn(input[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (kM * kN) / 256]);
    }
}

__global__
void int2half_I2H_tvm(int8_t* input, half* output){
    int rM = 8192;
    int rN = 8192;
    // #pragma unroll
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++ i){
        output[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (rM * rN) / 256] = \
            __int2half_rn(input[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (rM * rN) / 256]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    M=atoi(argv[1]);
    N=atoi(argv[2]);
    srand(time(NULL));

    // for int2half
    int8_t *input = (int8_t *)malloc(M * N);
    half *output_int2half = (half *)malloc(M * N * 2);

    // for prmt, + 128
    int8_t *input_preprocess = (int8_t *)malloc(M * N);
    half *output_prmt = (half *)malloc(M * N * 2);

    // result
    float *golden = (float *)malloc(M * N * 4);

    // rand input [-10, 10]
    for(int i = 0; i < M * N; ++ i){
        input[i] = (int8_t)((rand() % 21) - 10);
        golden[i] = (float)input[i];
    }

    // preprocess + 128
    for(int i = 0; i < M * N; ++ i){
        input_preprocess[i] = input[i] + 128;
    }

    int8_t *d_input;
    int8_t *d_input_preprocess;
    half *d_output_int2half;
    half *d_output_prmt;

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_input, M * N));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_input_preprocess, M * N));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_output_int2half, M * N * 2));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_output_prmt, M * N * 2));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_input, input, M * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_input_preprocess, input_preprocess, M * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));



    dim3 dimBlock(1024);
    dim3 dimGrid(256);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++ i){
        // printf("%d %d", M, N);
        //int2half_I2H_tvm<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>> (d_input, d_output_int2half);
        int2half_I2H_tvm<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>> (d_input, d_output_int2half,M,N);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }


    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(output_prmt, d_output_prmt, M * N * 2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(output_int2half, d_output_int2half, M * N * 2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


}
# nvcc -o t216 t216.cu -lineinfo
# compute-sanitizer ./t216 8192 8192
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
#


CUDA is prone to buffer overflow problems. You should always keep that in mind. In your code, this is the problematic line:

output[blockIdx.x * 1024 + threadIdx.x + i * (M * N) / 256] =...

Ask yourself what is the maximum value of the index expression? It seems to be 255*1024 + 1023 + M*N, which is greater than the allocated M*N elements.

CUDA is not any more or less prone to buffer overflow problems than regular C++ AFAIK.  And the calculation conducted at sufficient width does not result in a maximum value of the index expression that is greater than the allocated MxN elements.  The issue (which would be true for both C++ and CUDA C++ ) is integer overflow of an intermediate calculation result, which produces a negative resulting index, not an index that is greater than MxN.
